# Starting a new activity or intent in listview for certain items based on content rather than position

Tags: java, android, string, listview

I am wondering if it is possible to have clickable items in a listview that start a new activity or intent based upon the content of the items rather than position.  Each specific item needs to have a specific specific action and I want my app to be able to move items from the top or bottom in the listview or add them to a new list.  If the items are stationary, then basing the action on the item's position will work fine, but since the items will move, it will create problems.  Therefore, having the action based on the content of the items(Strings in this instnce) is the best bet, because it will work wherever the items are.

Currently, I am using `if (item_position==1)`, `if (item_position==2)`, if `(item_position==3)`,etc.  Here is the full code for reference:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> selectedItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        ListView chl = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.colorselector);
        chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        String[] items = {"Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "White", "Black", "Grey"};
        Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,items);
        chl.setAdapter(adapter);

        chl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                int item_position=i;
                if (item_position==1){

                }
```

Comment: I think you may need some more tutorials about listview. My blog about listview: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.com/. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> selectedItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView chl = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.colorselector);
    chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    String[] items = {"Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "White", "Black", "Grey"};
    Adapter adapter=new Adapter(this,items);
    chl.setAdapter(adapter);

    chl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(view instance of TextView){
               TextView textView=(TextView)view;
               String data=textView.getText();

               if(data.equal("Blue")){


               }else if(data.equals("Green")){


               }

            }




      }};
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the error "Incompatable types". Required: String, Found:Char sequence. I changed it but it does not work- it does not do anything when I click the items

Comment: textView.getText().toString();

Comment: use equal() instead of equals()

Comment: It is still giving me errors.  I also replaced it with == but it continues to give me errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the clicked item from the adapter using something like this:

```
String clickedItem = adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

I'm assuming the items your adapter holds are `String`s based on your example. You may need to cast the item to `String`:

```
String clickedItem = (String) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

or cast the `Adapter` to your specific implementation of adapter:

```
String clickedItem = ((MyAdapter)adapterView.getAdapter()).getItem(position);
```

Comment: @Fgf567 It seems that the item is of `CharSequence` type. You just need to cast it to `CharSequence` instead of `String`, (eg: `CharSequence clickedItem = (CharSequence) adapterView.getAdapter().getItem(position);`)